# Data transfer charges from internal ELB to instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

How much is the data transfer charges from internal-elb to instance.

Data transfer via private ip is: $0, so will data transfer via internal elb will be zero or I've to pay for the data transfer charges too ?

I know, it won't be much but still will it chargable?

Answer (score 3):

From https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/ it does sound like you would be charged.

E.g. US East (N. Virginia):

- $0.025 per Elastic Load Balancer-hour (or partial hour)
- $0.008 per GB of data processed by an Elastic Load Balancer

Comment: Yes, it seems to me too, but transfer via private-ip part is confusing me !

Comment: which part of the docs is confusing?  Behind the scenes, ELBs are just servers and you're getting charged for data transfer between those instances and your instances with behind them. Can you link the docs

Comment: In docs, it's written I'll be charged for data-transfer via ELB , but behind the scene(as you said) internal-ELBs are server's communicating with instance using private-ips AND data transfer via private-ip[since internal-ELB don't have public-IPs] is zero, so it's chargable or not chargable, this is where I got a doubt !

Comment: I think you can assume it's chargeable.  To the AWS customer, ELBs do not have private IP addresses.

Comment: @cjwfuller that last comment is incorrect.  ELBs are silently assigned private IP addresses in the subnets you place them in.  The answer is correct, though.  There's no charge for the "traffic" *per se*, but there is a charge for the "data processed."  ELBs are not fixed in size or number of nodes making up each one -- they scale with demand, and the "data processed" charge is how WAS covers the cost of the scaling, rather than charging per node or by the size of the nodes that comprise a single ELB.